# Global data with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, react-router

How do I maintain a central/global object for some data with react-router?

Let's say my React site has 20 different routes. 15 out of those 20 routes need one JSON file from the server that almost never changes. I hate having to GET "/api/mydata" for every new URL/route.

I guess I can save the data in [React's context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), but that seems hacky and may not even work. Is there a more elegant solution for sharing data between react-router components?

Edit: I partially solved this by creating a Data.js file:

```
export var myData = function(cb) {
  ajax('GET', '/api/mydata', resp => {
    myData = function() {
      return cb(resp);
    };
    cb(resp);
  });
};
```

and use it like this:

```
myData(data => data.map(/* ...use the data */));
```

That way the data is guaranteed to only be fetched once per lifecycle.

Comment: You can just store those data as a props in the root component and pass it to the child component. Routing in react-router will not reset the props. I suggest you to learn react-redux or flux, they solved your problem.

Comment: I've come across redux and flux and vaguely understood that this is the problem they solve, but I was too worried about adding _more_ KB's to my program

Comment: Redux is ~2kb. I don't think you should worry about that sort of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrr... if you don't want to use redux or flux, you can create a singleton like this in a new js file

```
let appState = {};
export default appState;
```

First do ajax to fill the data into this singleton. Then import it to everywhere you want the data.

Comment: Tried too long to get this to work...I'll just use redux in the future. For this project, I'll just play with the cache-control headers to keep things streamlined.